# Increase Performance Navigating Through Pages

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, performance

I’m using WinForms. My application works like a simple image document (tif) viewer. The tif/image documents I work with have multiple pages, so by pressing the next button my application goes to the next page. The problem with my application is that it is slow when I move to the next page. Previously, my application was slower. I’ve modified the application a little bit to make it faster, but it’s still not fast enough.

I’ve compared my application’s speed to Windows Photo Viewer and the result was that my application still needs improvement on performance. Does anyone know how I could make my application faster?

In the link below I’ve provided a sample tif document for testing purposes.

Link: http://www.filedropper.com/tiftestingdoc

My Code:

```
    FileStream _stream;
    Image _myImg; // setting the selected tiff
    string _fileName;
    private int intCurrPage = 0; // defining the current page

    private void Open_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; //Shows the filename in the lable

            Image img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = img;

            Size size = new Size(img.Height, img.Width);
            pictureBox1.Size = size;

            Open_Image_Control();

         }
    }

    public void Open_Image_Control()
    {
        Image myBmp;

        if (_myImg == null) //I made a copy of the file because i want to be able to modify the file in the directory for example go to directory and delete the file while still having the ability to view it on the application
        {
            _fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
            File.Copy(@"C:\my_Image_document", _fileName);
            _stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            _myImg = Image.FromStream(_stream);
        }

        int intPages = _myImg.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page); // getting the number of pages of this tiff
        intPages--; // the first page is 0 so we must correct the number of pages to -1
        lblNumPages.Text = Convert.ToString(intPages); // showing the number of pages
        lblCurrPage.Text = Convert.ToString(intCurrPage); // showing the number of page on which we're on

        _myImg.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, intCurrPage); // going to the selected page


        myBmp = new Bitmap(_myImg, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            //myBmp = new Bitmap(_myImg, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.Width);

        pictureBox1.Image = myBmp; // showing the page in the pictureBox1 
    }


    private void NextPage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (intCurrPage == Convert.ToInt32(lblNumPages.Text)) // if you have reached the last page it ends here
                                                              // the "-1" should be there for normalizing the number of pages
        { intCurrPage = Convert.ToInt32(lblNumPages.Text); }
        else
        {

            intCurrPage++; //page increment (Goes to next page)
            Open_Image_Control();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the image directly into the PictureBox, then to change pages call the `pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame()` method directly and refresh the PictureBox.

This prevents making new bitmaps copies of each page each time.
That was causing extra memory to be allocated each time and slowness while it copies all the pixels from the page.

Please see the code changes below:

```
        // Variable to hold the current page number
    private int intCurrPage = 0; 
    private int intTotalPages = 0;

    private void Open_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; 

            // Before loading you should check the file type is an image

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Height, pictureBox1.Image.Width);

            // Reset the current page when loading a new image
            intCurrPage = 0;
            intTotalPages = pictureBox1.Image.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
            lblNumPages.Text = intTotalPages.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void NextPage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check that the current page is not going past the max page
        if (intCurrPage < (intTotalPages-1))
        {
            //page increment (Go to next page)
            intCurrPage++;

            // Directly increment the active frame within the image already in the PictureBox
            pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, intCurrPage);

            // Adjust the size of the picturebox control to the size of the current page.
            // not sure if this is necessary, but including it due to prior example
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Height, pictureBox1.Image.Width);

            // Refresh the PictureBox so that it will show the currently active frame
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

            lblCurrPage.Text = intCurrPage.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Also, your code to copy the image had a hard coded directory name that was throwing errors for me, so I removed that.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain and helping me solve this issue. I really appreciate it! With a few modifications i was able to implement it into my main application.